# suprimir un títulos de un jtable

Tags: java, netbeans

quisiera saber como puedo esconder algunos títulos a mi jtable, ya que por ejemplo le quito y me manda error, osea

```
String[] titulos = {"ID", "Nombre", "Identificacion", "Edad", "Semestre", "ContactoEmNombre", "ContactoEmNumero", "MotivoConsulta", "AntecedentesPersonales", "RemisionS", "RemisionN","RemisionL", "NombrePsi", "Validacion","FechaActual","CorreoEstudiante","Celular","Parentesco","Area"};
```

tengo esta tabla pero como ven es muy grande y los titulos se comprimen para caber todos, lo que quiero es ocultar algunos y dejas solo unos pocos, el problema es que no puede quitarlos a si de simple porque pues me manda error.

asi traigo los datos de la bd a la tabla

```
 public void MostrarDatos(){
    conexion objConexion=new conexion();
    while(modelo.getRowCount()>0){
        modelo.removeRow(0);
    }
        try {
        ResultSet resultado=objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM Estudiantes");
        while (resultado.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ID"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Nombre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("FechaNacimiento"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Identificacion"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Edad"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Semestre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ContactoEmNombre"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("ContactoEmNumero"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("MotivoConsulta"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("AntecedentesPersonales"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionS"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionN"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("RemisionL"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("NombrePsicologa"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Validacion"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("FechaActual"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("CorreoEstudiante"));  
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Celular"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Parentesco"));
            System.out.println(resultado.getString("Area"));

            Object[] oUsuario={resultado.getString("ID"),resultado.getString("Nombre"),resultado.getString("FechaNacimiento"),resultado.getString("Identificacion"),resultado.getString("Edad"),resultado.getString("Semestre"),resultado.getString("ContactoEmNombre"),resultado.getString("ContactoEmNumero"),resultado.getString("MotivoConsulta"),resultado.getString("AntecedentesPersonales"),resultado.getString("RemisionS"),resultado.getString("RemisionN"),resultado.getString("RemisionL"),resultado.getString("NombrePsicologa"),resultado.getString("Validacion"),resultado.getString("FechaActual"), resultado.getString("CorreoEstudiante"), resultado.getString("Celular"), resultado.getString("Parentesco"), resultado.getString("Area")};
            modelo.addRow(oUsuario);
        }
```

Comment: Saludos @JM, agrega un poco más de detalle ¿Lo que quieres es quitar la columna completa?, agrega también que haz probado y cual es el error que mencionas que te muestra, recuerda siempre agregar todos los detalles posibles para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de manera precisa. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Dejo el cambio de tabla seteada en numero de columnas necesarias aclarando que la matriz mostraras únicamente las columnas que necesitas.  pero dependerá de donde alimentas la tabla pero considero que este ejemplo cumple con lo que requieres según el comentario y no en base a la consulta original

```
   ArrayList<facturafor> lista = new ArrayList<facturafor>();

public Detalle() {
    initComponents();
    setTitle("Detalle de compras");
}

public void mostrar() {
    String item[][] = new String[lista.size()][13];
    for (int i = 0; i <= lista.size() - 1; i++) {
        item[i][0] = lista.get(i).getSala();
        item[i][1] = lista.get(i).getNsala();
        item[i][2] = lista.get(i).getUnidad();
        item[i][3] = lista.get(i).getPrecio();
        item[i][4] = lista.get(i).getPm();            
        item[i][5] = lista.get(i).getTotalitem();
    }
    Tabla.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel (
            item,
            new String[]{
                "Sucursal", "Nombre","Cantidad","Precio", "Desc", "Subtotal"
            }
    ));
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Tabla);
    if (Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(25);
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(40);
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(30);
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(40);
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(30);
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(40);
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(30);
        Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(45);
    }
}
```

en el init component

```
Tabla.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Sucursal", "Nombre", "Cantidad", "Precio", "Pant/Mujer", "Precio", "Falda", "Precio", "Camisa", "Precio", "Pant/Hombre ", "Precio ", "Subtotal"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Tabla);
        if (Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(30);
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(25);
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(40);
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(30);
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(40);
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(30);
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(40);
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(30);
            Tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(40);
        }
```

Comment: lo deje solo con las comillas pero  de igual manera me queda el espacio en la tabla, osea lo que quiero es que en la tabla me muestre solo unos 4 datos pero como estan los espacio de todos se comprimen y toca manualmente abrirlos para ver el titulo completo

Comment: en ese caso no es como esta formulada la pregunta, entiendo que necesitas mostrar solo x columnas independientes de su titulo? si es asi bastara con setear la tabla con las columnas requeridas y el array correspondiente por favor coloca el codigo completo de la tabla no solamente el set de titulos.

Comment: dejo editada la respuesta con ejemplo pero alimentada desde un clase con constructor.

Comment: la tabla la lleno de una base de datos,

Comment: solo rellenas la tabla con los items que necesitas. y la seteas con la nueva cantidad de columnas.  si ves la respuesta el ejemplo es de 13 columnas pero solo muestro 6 columnas en la tabla con datos.  agrega en la pregunta como obtienes los datos y como los pasas al array de la tabla.